# A Fibonacci convolution

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, convolution, fibonacci-numbers

> A Fibonacci convolution. Recall that $$F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty F_n x^n =\frac{x}{1-x-x^2} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left(\frac{1}{1-\Phi x} -\frac{1}{1-\bar{\Phi}x}\right).$$
>   (a) Prove that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty F_{n+1} x^n =\frac{1}{1-x-x^2}$.
>
> (b) Prove that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty (2F_{n+1} -F_n)x^n =\frac{2-x}{1-x-x^2} =\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\Phi^n +\bar{\Phi}^n) x^n$.
>
> (c) Prove that $\displaystyle 5F(x)^2 =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+1}{1} \Phi^n x^n -2\sum_{n=0}^\infty F_{n+1} x^n +\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+1}{1} \bar{\Phi}^n x^n$.
>
> **(d) Prove that $\boldsymbol{\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n F_k F_{n-k} =\frac{2n F_{n+1} -(n+1)F_n}{5}}$.**

I've gotten through (a)-(c) but I don't know how to start (d).

Comment: Start by noting that the convolution is the generating function for $F(x)^2$.

Comment: That, or bash it by strong induction on $n$ (as usual for Fibonacci-number identities, going down by $1$ and $2$ in the induction step).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have already mastered a.) to c.) we can conveniently use the results to prove d.).

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{5F(x)^2}&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)\left(\Phi^n+\bar{\Phi}^n\right)x^n-2\sum_{n=0}^\infty F_{n+1}x^n\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)\left(2F_{n+1}-F_n\right)x^n-2\sum_{n=0}^\infty F_{n+1}x^n\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(2nF_{n+1}-(n+1)F_n\right)x^n}
> \end{align*}
>   and d.) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply c.) by using $\binom{n+1}{1}=n+1$ and collecting the first and the last sum.
- In (2) we use from b.) the identity $2F_{n+1}-F_n=\Phi^n+\bar{\Phi}^n$.