Coincidence with the recurrence and solution for Fibonacci convolution?
When playing around trying to answer a question, I discovered a curious recurrence and solution for the Fibonacci convolution
$$a_n=\sum_{i+j=n} f_i f_j$$
where $f_i$ is ith element the Fibonacci sequence, defined by $f_0=0, f_1=1, f_{n+1}=f_n+f_{n-1}$.
One can show that $a_n$ satisfies the recurrence relation $a_{n+1}+a_{n-1}=nf_n$ and will have solution $5a_n=(n-1)f_{n+1}+(n+1)f_{n-1}$.  The symmetry here feels like it belies a deeper fact or principle, but I can't tell what.
So, are there general conditions under which we have
$$a_{n+1}+a_{n-1}=nb_n,\qquad ca_n=(n-1)b_{n+1}+(n+1)b_{n-1}$$
or was this just an interesting coincidence?  I suspect that one can work out what the conditions should be for this to happen in terms of generating functions, but when I was trying, the equations were complicated looking and unenlightening.

Edited to add: The way I initially found the recurrence was by using the identity $f_{i+1}f_{j+1}+f_{i}f_{j}=f_{i+j+1}$.  Then $$\begin{align}\sum_{\substack{i+j=n,\\i>0,j>0}} f_if_j&=\sum_{i+j=n,i>0,j>0} f_{n-1}-f_{i-1}f_{j-1}  \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} f_{n-1} + \sum_{\substack{(i-1)+(j-1)=n-2,\\i-1\geq 0, j-1 \geq 0}}f_{i-1}f_{j-1} \\
&= (n-1)f_{n-1} + \sum_{\substack{i+j=n-2,\\i\geq 0, j\geq 0}}f_{i}f_{j}  \end{align}.$$
Then, the fact that $f_0=0$ and a simple reindexing yields $a_{n+1}+a_{n-1}=nf_n$.

It seems like you likely want to look at generating function.

The self-convolution of the Fibonacci sequence is documented on OEIS as A001629. In particular, it includes the formula $a_n=\frac15 (n-1)f_{n+1}+\frac15 (n+1)f_{n-1}$.

An important source of information on issues related to Fibonacci sequence (but not only) is the "Fibonacci Quarterly" journal, for example with this article

Consider the system of two equations
$$
\begin{cases}
a_{n+1} + a_{n-1} = nb_n, \\
c a_n = (n-1) b_{n+1} + (n+1) b_{n-1}
\end{cases}
$$
We need to describe all pairs of sequences $(a_n, b_n)$ that satisfy the recurrence above.
Let $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ be OGFs of $a_n$ and $b_n$ and $\Delta = x \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$. Also assume that $a_0=b_0=0$, so that $\frac{A(x)}{x}$ and $\frac{B(x)}{x}$ are still meaningful expressions. Then, the first recurrence rewrites as
$$
(x^{-1}+x)A(x) = \Delta B(x),
$$
and the second recurrence rewrites as
$$
cA(x) = (\Delta-1) x^{-1} B(x) + (\Delta+1) xB(x).
$$
However, we should note that, unlike the previous recurrence, this one only works for $n > 0$ with Fibonacci numbers, which we can fix by subtracting a constant $t=b_1$ on the right hand side.
Getting rid of $A(x)$ in them, we arrive at
$$
c\Delta B(x) = (x^{-1}+x) [(\Delta-1) x^{-1} B(x) + (\Delta+1) xB(x)-t]
$$
Expanding $\Delta$ back, we get the differential equation
$$
cxB'(x) = (x^{-1}+x) [B'(x) - 2x^{-1}B(x) +x^2 B'(x) +2xB(x)-t]
$$
This simplifies into
$$
cx^3B'(x) = x(1+x^2)^2 B'(x) + 2(x^4-1)B(x)-t(x+x^3)
$$
As WolframAlpha suggest, the general solution to this is
$$
\boxed{B(x) = \frac{tx(1-x^2)+k_1 x^2}{1-(c-2)x^2+x^4}}
$$
In particular, for $c=5$, $t=1$ and $k_1=1$, we get
$$
B(x) = \frac{x+x^2-x^3}{1-3x^2+x^4} = \frac{x}{1-x-x^2}.
$$
We can also get a generic expression for $A(x)$:
$$
\boxed{A(x) = \frac{x^2 \left( t (1+(c-6)x^2+x^4) + 2 k_1 x(1-x^2) \right)}{\left(1-(c-2) x^2 + x^4 \right)^2}}
$$
The result generally looks less than satisfactory, because other than $c=5, t=1, k_1=1$ there doesn't seem to be any particularly interesting set of parameters. Note that there might be further solutions to the recurrences if we drop the $a_0=b_0=0$ constraint, but I don't think it's likely to find anything interesting there, while it also will entail new technical challenges to account for them.

I think one way to ensure (or make them more likely) more interesting results in this case would be to reformulate the question e.g. as follows: Let's say $B(x)$ adheres to some simple linear recurrence. When is it possible to express self-convolution of $b_n$ as a simple function of finite amount of $b_n, b_{n-1}, \dots$?

Let me first give a small array with the first $f_n$ and $a_n$ ; this array can be of some help for the "verification" of certain relationships
$$\begin{array}{|l|rrrrrrrrrr|} \hline
n&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&\cdots\\
\hline 
f_n&0&1&1&2&3&5&8&13&21&\cdots\\
\hline
a_n&0&0&1&2&5&10&20&38&71&\cdots\\
\hline
\end{array}$$
(see reference in EOIS found by @Semiclassical where many formulas connecting the $f_n$ and $a_n$ are given).

The generating function of the Fibonacci sequence is :

$$\sum f_n x^n= \frac{x}{1-x-x^2}\tag{1}$$

The generating function of the convolution of two sequences being the product of their generating functions, we get :

$$\sum a_n x^n= \left(\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}\right)^2\tag{2}$$
Besides, differentiating (1) :
$$\sum nf_n x^{n-1}= \frac{x^2+1}{(1-x-x^2)^2}$$
$$\frac{x^2+1}{x^2}\frac{x^2}{(1-x-x^2)^2}=\sum nf_n x^{n-1} $$
Otherwise said :
$$(x^2+1)\sum a_n x^n=x^2 \sum nf_n x^{n-1}$$
Identifying like coefficients, we get :
$$a_{n-1}+a_{n+1}=nf_n$$
which is (one of) your relationship(s).
(A big big thank to @Semiclassical who has found a correct (!) path to the result, correcting my initial erroneous conclusion).
Remark : we haven't placed bounds ($n=$ ... to ...) on the $\Sigma$ symbols in order not to be bothered by the first terms' irregularities, being understood that the different operations involved have an impact on the first coefficients only without impairing the general term.

One observation is that, after differentiating (2), one has $$(1+x^2)\sum a_n x^n=x^2 \sum nf_n x^{n-1}$$ Multiplying the factors through and identifying term-by-term yields $a_{n-1}+a_{n+1}=nf_n$.

@Semiclassical A big big thank !

I'm not sure if it's the most elementary way to prove it, but it appears that the other formula (expressing $a_n$ in terms of $f_n$) amounts to the following: Let $F(x)=x/(1-x-x^2)$. Then $$(D_x x^4+x^2 D_x)x^{-2} F(x)=5F(x)^2-1.$$ (Which is, indeed, far from obvious---this is very much a mechanical proof.)

... which is less evident...

@Semiclassical Connected : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3016349/305862

That proof of Markus is marvelously tidier than what I had. Thanks!

An (anonymous !)  downvoter... I would like to know what is the issue with this solution...

Hey there, the anonymous down-voter here! The issue is that the answer does not address the actual question, which is: "are there general conditions, under which we have...". Furthermore, even for particular case, the answer only addresses the recurrence $a_{n-1} + a_{n+1} = n f_n$, but not $5a_n = (n-1) f_{n+1} + (n+1) f_{n-1}$.

@Oleksandr Kulkov I appreciate your fair-play. But you recognize yourself that I have given a full answer to one among two questions : this doesn't deserve a downvote, IMHO.

@JeanMarie It is not an answer to any of the questions I asked.  I said "I found that we satisfied a recurrence, and it had a particular solution, I want to understand if there are deeper reasons" and you showed me why the initial recurrence was true.  I knew why the initial recurrence was true, which is why I went back and edited the problem to give a simpler proof for why the recurrence was true.  You misunderstood me giving context for me asking an additional question.

Anyway, if you haven't learned anything new from me (in particular the generating functions technique), I thank you for this question which, on my side, has given me the opportunity to learn new things :)

@JeanMarie I'm glad that the problem was enjoyable for you.  Even if it wasn't addressing what I wanted, it is still a good answer to a different question, and I appreciate the effort either way, so I will not be downvoting it, though at this point I have not upvoted it either.
